# How to get children prop from parent's styled-component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-props, children

Let's say I have this component:

```
const TopBar: FunctionComponent<TopBarProps> = ({
  mode,
  iconMode,
  justified,
  sticky,
  children,
}: TopBarProps) => {
  return (
    <StyledTopBar
      as={justified ? 'div' : 'header'}
      px={justified ? [-4, -4, 0] : [4, 4, 6, 6]}
      height="size11"
      mode={mode}
      iconMode={iconMode}
      sticky={sticky}
    >
      <TopBarWrapper justified={justified}>{children}</TopBarWrapper>
    </StyledTopBar>
  );
};
```

And this is styledTopBar:

```
interface StyledTopBarProps extends SpaceProps, LayoutProps {
    mode: TopBarProps['mode'];
    iconMode: TopBarProps['iconMode'];
    sticky?: boolean;
}


const StyledTopBar = styled('header').withConfig({
    shouldForwardProp,
  })<StyledTopBarProps>`
    /* more styles were here */
    ${({ theme, mode, isOpen }) =>
      variant({
        prop: 'iconMode',
        variants: {
          light: {
            color: 'text.text1Inverse',
            span: { // <----  this is the span
              color: 'text.text1Inverse',
            },
          },
          dark: {
            color: 'text.link',
            span: { // <----  this is the span
              color: 'text.link',
            },
          },
        },
      })}
    ${variant({
      prop: 'sticky',
      variants: {
        true: {
          position: 'fixed',
          zIndex: 'header',
        },
      },
    })}
  `;
```

So turns out on of the `{children}` is this component, which prints a `<span>`:

```
    interface StyledNavIconProps extends SpaceProps, LayoutProps {
    mode: 'dark' | 'light';
    isOpen: boolean;
}

const getBorderColor = (colors, mode: string, isOpen: boolean) => {
    if (!isOpen) return colors.special.transparent;
        return mode === 'dark' ? colors.focus.light : colors.focus.focus;
    };

const StyledNavIcon = styled('span').withConfig({
    shouldForwardProp,
})<StyledNavIconProps>`
    cursor: pointer;
    /* ... */
    border-color: ${(props) => getBorderColor(props.theme.colors, props.mode, props.isOpen)};
    /* ... */
`;
```

So in the initial component (StyledTopBar) I need to know if that children isOpen or not to apply the required styles to the span

So I tried like this:

```
const getIconBorderColor = (colors, mode: string, isOpen: boolean) => {
  if (!isOpen) return colors.special.transparent;
  return mode === 'dark' ? colors.focus.light : colors.focus.focus;
};

const StyledTopBar = styled('header').withConfig({
    shouldForwardProp,
  })<StyledTopBarProps>`
    ${({ theme, mode, isOpen }) =>
      variant({
        prop: 'iconMode',
        variants: {
          light: {
            color: 'text.text1Inverse',
            span: { // <----  this is the span
              color: 'text.text1Inverse',
              borderColor: `${({ theme, mode, isOpen }) => getIconBorderColor(theme.colors, mode, isOpen)}`,
  
              '&:hover, &:focus, &:focus-within, &:active': {
                borderColor: 'text.text1Inverse',
                background: 'transparent',
              },
            },
          },
          dark: {
            color: 'text.link',
            span: {
              color: 'text.link',
            },
          },
        },
      })}
    
  `;
```

But is there a way to import the isOpen property?

Of course the IDE is yelling at me
[image]

any thoughts?

Comment: In all seriousness: ditch `styled-components`. Use plain old function components and corresponding css-modules. Keeps you sane and your code maintainable.

Comment: if only I could.. I'm making this adjustment for a client..

Comment: My deepest condolences. May God be with you. You are a braver man than I ever can hope to be.